# Bullet physics incorrect rotation with more than one axis

Tags: opengl, bullet-physics, glm

im try to integrate currently bullet into my game framework. But when i try to set the rotation for an rigidbody with more the 1 axis i recive the current result

[image]

It looks that the rotation is mirrored. If i set only 1 axis everything is fine.

Here is how i try to set the location, rotation and scale

```
public void UpdateRigidBody()
    {
        Vec3 location = Utils.GetElementWorldLocation(Parent);
        Vec3 rotation = Utils.GetElementWorldRotation(Parent);

        BulletSharp.Math.Matrix transform = BulletSharp.Math.Matrix.Translation(location.X, location.Y, location.Z);
        BulletSharp.Math.Matrix rotMat = BulletSharp.Math.Matrix.RotationYawPitchRoll(rotation.Y, rotation.X, rotation.Z);/* BulletSharp.Math.Matrix.RotationX(rotation.X) * BulletSharp.Math.Matrix.RotationY(rotation.Y) * BulletSharp.Math.Matrix.RotationZ(rotation.Z);*/
        this.RigidBody.MotionState = new DefaultMotionState(transform * rotMat);

        Vec3 scale = Utils.GetElementWorldScale(this.Parent);
        this.RigidBody.CollisionShape.LocalScaling = new Vector3(scale.X, scale.Y, scale.Z);
    }
```

and here is how i set the matrix for the rendering with glmsharp

```
  public static mat4 GetModelRotation(GameElement element)
    {
        Vec3 rotation = Utils.GetElementWorldRotation(element);
        return mat4.RotateX(rotation.X) * mat4.RotateY(rotation.Y) * mat4.RotateZ(rotation.Z);
    }
    
    //// within the rendering
    
    mat4 mt_mat = Utils.GetModelTransformation(element);
mat4 mr_mat = Utils.GetModelRotation(element);
mat4 ms_mat = Utils.GetModelScale(element);
mat4 m_mat = mt_mat * mr_mat * ms_mat;
mat4 mvp = p_mat * v_mat * m_mat;
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Your rendering rotation matrix order looks unusual. I'm used to seeing yaw-pitch-roll (Y-X-Z according to the order you passed to Bullet), but here you seem to be doing pitch-yaw-roll

Comment: Ah yeah. I changed this allready. to this

`BulletSharp.Math.Matrix transform = BulletSharp.Math.Matrix.Translation(location.X, location.Y, location.Z);
BulletSharp.Math.Matrix rotMat = BulletSharp.Math.Matrix.RotationX(rotation.X) * BulletSharp.Math.Matrix.RotationY(rotation.Y) * BulletSharp.Math.Matrix.RotationZ(rotation.Z);
this.RigidBody.MotionState = new DefaultMotionState(transform * rotMat);`

but still mirrored if i change more then 1 axis.

Comment: Be sure to edit your question to show your current code then.